# Hosting a WCF endpoint with programatic settings in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis

I need to host a WCF service in IIS that exposes a wsHttpBinding. That part is working nicely using the settings of system.serviceModel in my web.config.

What i need now is to setup the configuration (like maxReceivedMessageSize and other options) through a configuration assembly that is also used by the client(s).

How is this possible? I see no handles in my .svc file like in my client to overload binding configuration. I suspect this is because it is automaticly handled by ISS when the application starts up as in contrast to a windows service where you have to manually declare the client/channel.

Am i right about this? And would the solution to his problem (if i still want hosting inside IIS) to remove all configuration and instead create a HttpHandler that takes care of the hosting on startup?

If i'm right i guess i just wasted a whole lot of space writing this, but i can't help thinking i'm missing something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing something :)

Create a custom [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) and [use that in the .svc file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395224.aspx); in the custom service host do all your configuration

Comment: Thanks - just what i needed. A much better looking solution than what i was fearing :)